# Java program ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing two recursive java programs, however they both have errors. The largest method has an out of bounds error on the final return. The second code says max is an incompatible type. 
I am fairly new at Java and the codes probably look a little messy so any tips on how to make it easier or nicer are welcome!

this program finds the largest digit in the array:

```
   public static int largest(int data[], int n) {
      if (n == 0) {
      } 
      return largest(data, 0, n-1);  //line107
   }

   public static int largest(int array[], int LF, int RT){
      if (LF == RT){ //1 element array
      }

      else { 
      //   int large = largest(array, LF++, size - 1);
       //  return x = 

         int largeLF = array[LF];
         int largeRT = array[RT];  
         int mid = ((RT - LF) / 2) + LF;
         if (LF < mid - 1){
            if (array[LF] > largeLF){
               largeLF = array[LF];
            }
            largest(array, LF + 1, RT); //line 125
         }
         else if (RT > mid - 1){
            if (array[RT] > largeRT){
               largeRT = array[RT];
            }
            largest(array, LF, RT - 1); //line 131
         }
         else {
            if (array[mid] > largeLF){
               largeLF = array[mid];
            }    
         }
         if (largeRT > largeLF){
            LF = largeRT;

         }
         LF = largeLF;
      }
      return array[LF]; //line 144
   }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:144)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:131)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:131)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:125)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:125)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:125)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:125)
    at ArrayUtilities.largest(ArrayUtilities.java:107)
    at ArrayUtilitiesTest.main(ArrayUtilitiesTest.java:5)
```

this code finds the block of numbers with the greatest sum

```
   public static int maxBlock(int data[], int n) {
      if (n == 0) {
      } 
      else {
         maxBlock(data, n-1);
      }
      return n;
   }

   public static void maxBlock(int data[], int LF, int RT) {
      int n = RT;
      for (LF = 0; LF < n; LF++){
         for (RT = LF; RT < n; RT++){
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = LF; i <= RT; i++){
               sum += data[i];
            }
            int max = data[0];
            for (LF = 0; LF < n; LF++){
               sum = 0;
               for (RT = LF; RT < n; RT++){
                  sum += data[RT];   
                  if (sum > max){
                     max = sum;
                  }
                  System.out.println(max);
               }
            }
           return max;
         } 
      }
   }
```

I am still confused on the returns since they are not global variables, how do you transfer the values?

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: At what point you are getting the exception?

Comment: After the final return on the second largest method. 
I changed my script a bit on the second code, maxBlock, and now it's showing an incompatible data type, although don't I have to return a number to the first maxBlock in order for it to return the final number?

Comment: You need to be specific. You should edit your question and narrow down to a particular problem. You should clearly specify in the question that at what point you are getting the error. People are not going to debug all your code line by line and find the solution for you. I think you get the point. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ashleyqbana: Please print your exception

Comment: What's with the empty blocks on your `if (...)` statements?  That's downright evil!

Comment: @pjs My professor told me to leave them empty if nothing was being done  so that it would be easier to see. o.o What would make it not evil?

Comment: Read about ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html . I hope my comment help you fix the bug

Comment: @ashleyqbana Would your professor advocate putting in hundreds of other `if` statements for the hundreds of other things you're *not* doing?  Instead of writing `if (n == 0) {} else {do something}`, just write `if (n != 0) {do something}`.  Test only for things you plan to do, and test them directly rather than making them the `else` clause.